# How to load async react components without Webpack imports with SSR and RR4

Tags: reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering, code-splitting

I have been looking for a good solution to load async react components on demand at matched route without Webpack import, System.import, require.ensure, ...

I want to **avoid Webpack footprints in client-side code**.

On Server I fetch all routes and render matched locations as static HTML/JS. Like classic SSR.

## My solution is:

- Pack async Components with Webpack to static bundles (*c1.js*, c2.js, ...)
- Store Map for Routes => async Components as json ("/path" => *c1.js*)
- Request React-Rroute(RR4) matched path with param `wrap=true` over ajax
- If route exists, and param `wrap=true` render *c1.js* on server to fetch data (universal ajax) from DB
- Wrap data and raw *c1.js* as script response
- Append response as script child at body or parent React Component Dom
- Script unwraps data and code, stores them (e.g. Redux) and append/render async component (*c1.js*) to React Dom

**This way i have a small entry file and could:**

1. request route `https://host` and load component (/path) on demand
2. request route `https://host/path` on entry and render compleate components (no async)
3. request route `https://host/path` with RR4 and fetch and render async component(s)
4. reload page like 2.
5. use browser history (back-forward) without requests for data or components (both exist in Redux store and script tag)
6. Be able to use component with pagination (load more data and reuse fetched component)

**My thoughts on this:**
 Render async components direct to Dom instead cache them in script tag will lose component code on unmount parent Component (because async component not exist in main.bundle.js)

## Questions:

- Is there a proven approach to handle async component loading (**React code only** and without **Webpack hacky imports**) and be able to render universal?
- Is it bad practice to split react code over independent bundles?

  ```
  `<script src=bundle.js /><script>*c1.js* code</script>`
  ```
- Is it bad practice to appand script tag to react component dom (like `<App/>` or `<Home/>`)

  - Whats about HMR (Maybe side effects)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would have to use any Webpack specific code in your client-side code? The below is from a library called `react-loadable`. The only Webpack specific hack you can do is put a Webpack specific comment near the import to make it use the name specified.

```
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import Loading from './my-loading-component';

const LoadableComponent = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./my-component'),
  loading: Loading,
});

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <LoadableComponent/>;
  }
}
```

This is the library I would suggest you start using when you want to do code-splitting. Especially if you also want to do SSR. It has a few utility classes to help you with that.